# Question about meaning of "very own" and "one yourself" and one more word in this text

Tags: word-meaning

> Dealing with the **office** Kanye
>
> Are you working with your **very own** Kanye West?
>
> Here’s how to deal with talented colleagues who steal the limelight at work. Plus, avoid this response if you don’t want to look like **one yourself** .

My first concern has to do with the word **office** . why did they say office kanya? Why they didn't say Kanye West? Is **office** here an adjective. I know of course it is a noun and I am confused.
I have  no idea what **very own** and **one yourself** here mean.

Here is source: http://www.bbc.com/capital/story/20150212-dealing-with-the-office-kanye

Answer (score 2):

The "office Kanye" is a co-worker who behaves like Kanye. "Office" in this context refers to something or someone whose behavior is pertinent at the workplace. Someone at your office who behaves foolishly might be called "the office clown".

"Very own" is actually part of the phrase "your very own". The phrase "(possessive pronoun) very own" is used to establish exclusive ownership - an advertisement might say, "and now you can have one for your very own". The phrase is normally used when having something "for your very own" is a good thing. In this case the phrase is being used ironically, and the sentence means "Are you working with someone who makes a scene inappropriately?"

"Yourself", in this case, can be considered the equivalent of "too". That is, if you use this response, you will be perceived as acting just like the other person.